# New to Ubuntu, trying to install and run WoW MOP & LoL

Tags: 12.04, wine, games, playonlinux

I am new to Ubuntu Linux, just came from windows 7 after a recommendation from one of my guild mates on GW2. Sadly I should have grilled him more on how to install all of the games and run them. I have spent a couple days now trying everything from Wine, to Playonlinux, to Q4linux, Virtualbox, etc and running random stuff that I don't even know on the terminal. I have gotten league using playonlinux as far as installed but it freezes at 33% update. I am using ubuntu 12.04 because 12.10 was giving me a blank screen with just a mouse pointer and my background when I switched to my proprietary Nvidia 210 GeForce video card, but 12.04 did not have a problem switching over. Well if anyone knows of a good guide to tell me how to install and run WoW MOP using the client off of battle.net and/or a league of legends guide as well I will be eternally grateful! Well, I am off to keep searching through google and learn more since I am determined to learn this OS.

Guide to install and run WoW and LoL please? New to Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Next time you are asking a question, consider asking several questions, one for each of your problems. In this case: One question for WoW and one for LoL. Additionally make sure that you don't ask questions that have already been asked and already have an answer.

Comment: I didnt want to ask this question, but i went all through google, trying all the guides and forums and they didnt work, just got it to work now and not even the guide he posted got it fixed all the way. I had to go through many guides just to get it to work. Making me wonder why no one has compiled all of these issues into one big guide yet.

Answer (score 4):

I hope you installed Ubuntu alongside Windows because if this fails then you can always go back to playing the games on Windows and doing work etc... on Ubuntu.

Let's go through this step by step:

League of Legends: 
[WineHQ page](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19141)

World of Warcraft: 
[WineHQ page](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1922)

Both LoL and WoW seem to have good test reports for Wine 1.5 (beta) so run the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

that will install the beta version of Wine (as well as keeping it updated). You can then download each installer, right-click on them in your file manager and click: 
Open With > Wine Windows Program Loader 
then run the installer WITHOUT CHANGING ANY OF THE DEFAULTS.
The desktop links don't normally work, so try finding the actual executable in '~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files' in your file manager (press Ctrl + H to see hidden files like .wine)

You can also try:

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.4
```

after adding the PPA as mentioned before to try the 'stable' version of Wine.

This probably won't work, so go to the webpages that I linked you to and check on there for solutions to bugs. I couldn't get LoL to work but it would be great if you could.

Comment: The WoW version seems to work and I will try the LoL after this. Thank you alot. I think the reason is I was trying to run it under wine 1.4 instead of the beta version. And no i didnt keep it for a dual boot, I am a broke college student so my windows was ripped off line lol and it was using an unusually large amount of resources. My computer performance was constantly over %70 and considering i just built this computer last year it should not have been acting that way.

Comment: Oh, got league to work btw just using play on linux, the winehq guide kept giving me black screen. but ever time i re ran the client it required me to patch and the patch takes like 2 hours..

Comment: I am rather surprised that it worked because although I love Wine it is VERY unreliable and incomplete. Wine is better than Windows 8 at running really old games though due to a lack of 16-bit support in Windows 8.

That is a weird bug you mentioned about League, I would recommend filing it as a bug report in the League of Legends section on WineHQ.

And I respect you for trying to game with Ubuntu on its own but, then again, Ubuntu is actually decent for gaming now (thanks Valve).

Comment: I spoke to soon. Yes I did get league to work with POL, and I was able to run it. But oddly enough after exiting, when I came back to run a new game the client wants to do the same 2 hour patch all over again. I am not sure what it is but I will figure this out and post my findings.

Comment: This guide covers the new battle.net installer well.
http://geebzor.com/tech/linux/wow-ubuntu-14-04-trusty/